# ng-repeat not working with Firebreath plugin object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebreath

I am just beginning with AngularJS and I am trying to use ng-repeat on the Firebreath plugin and it doesn't seem to work.

```
<div ng-controller="PluginCtrl">
   <object type='application/x-sometype' ng-repeat='plugin in plugins' 
        id='pluginobj_{{plugin.id}}'>
   </object>
</div>
```

And my controller file has code which looks like:

```
var app = angular.module("appName");
app.controller("PluginCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.plugins = {};
   $scope.plugins["1"] = {id: "1"};
   $scope.plugins["2"] = {id: "2"};
});
```

I know this is an issue with Firebreath's JSAPI because it works really well if I change the object 'type' to something else. I did not go deep down yet on what's the cause of this but I guess some of the object dom properties angularJS needs when computing with ng-repeat is missing in the JSAPI. It would be helpful if someone knows why this is the case or already came across this. Thanks in advance.

Edit: By not working I mean the {{plugin.id}} is not being substituted by the values 1 & 2 from the scope, though two object elements are being created in the dom.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not JSAPI specifically, it's plugins in general.  I doubt that it would work with Flash either.  I am not 100% certain of that, but I did at one point spend a day or so trying to fix it and ended up just getting deeper and deeper into some of the weirdest issues I've ever encountered.

The number of reasons why this would be a bad idea is longer than I can even remember, and I wrote FireBreath.  Suffice it to say that it is not likely to *ever* work well to do what you're doing.  For one thing, you should never set the type of an object tag before adding it into the DOM because the browser in some cases (depending on browser, OS, and version) will actually reinstantiate the plugin instance when you remove it and add it elsewhere, which angular will tend to do in certain cases.

I really recommend only using a plugin by injecting the html directly in, or, if you won't accept that, setting the type after it's been rendered.  You should be able to rig up a directive to make this happen however it needs to, including if necessary adding multiple instances of the plugin.

You are also welcome to spend some time trying to fix it; I have already done so, and I don't consider it worth my time to spend any further time on it.

Comment: Thank Taxilian for your response. I've checked with changing the object type to x-shockwave-flash before and it was working properly. It's also working properly with the many other type of html elements.

Comment: Not sure why I'm not allowed a new line but I will continue here. I did not quite get what you mentioned about removing and adding the plugin by the browser. In my use-case once the plugin is instantiated, I would not remove/add the plugins from the dom but only reposition them later (I run video on the plugin). I can try with injecting the html in the controller/directive but I've been reading material that this is not a good AngularJS practice which is what I am skeptical of.

Comment: You are correct; it's not good angularJS practice.  However, you're not doing something that is typical angularJS stuff to do, so you can be excused in this case.

Suffice it to say that there are some significant issues caused in some browsers (it's inconsistent) by removing a plugin from the DOM and re-inserting it. You Have Been Warned.